# How to add a value to a string?

Tags: c, string, sdl, chars

I am using C and the SDL library and am trying to express something like the following code:

```
Surface = SDL_LoadBMP("Resources/Images/ButtonPlay.bmp");
```

as something like this:

```
ButtonName = "ButtonPlay";
Surface = SDL_LoadBMP("Resources/Images/"+ButtonName+".bmp");
```

to introduce some type of templating.

I have tried various codes (including some from similar questions) and cannot get it to work.

I just want a quick and easy way to do it, preferably without any additional library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `strcat` function (http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

It allows you to join two string by appending the src arg to the dest arg.

```
ButtonName = "ButtonPlay";
res = strcat("Resources/Images/", ButtonName);
res = strcat(res, ".bmp");
Surface = SDL_LoadBMP(res);
```

You can find easier ways to do this but this one is clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have an issue including <stdio.h> then you can do the following

```
char ResourcePath[1024];
ButtonName = "ButtonPlay";

sprintf(ResourcePath, "Resources/Images/%s.bmp", ButtonName);

Surface = SDL_LoadBMP(ResourcePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have run intro some trouble with your code. I used this    `char ResourcePath[1024];
 char ButtonName = "Play";

 sprintf_s(ResourcePath, "Resources/Images/%s.bmp", ButtonName);` but it does not work. It just enters and exits the application. I had to use `sprintf_s` because my compiler gave me a security error.

Comment: @Inventor as documentation says, `sprintf_s` is not the same as `sprintf`. In your case, you have provided wrong second argument - `sprintf_s` requires explicit maximum size of buffer it will print to. "Doesn't work" and "enters and exits" is not a programmer's type of phrases - if you have problem, you have to describe it in a very specific way.

Comment: And I did describe it as specific as I could. The code did compile and the application run, but it exited the same second as it initialized. I am not aware and not proficient in using any other ways of debugging. After examining the documentation I indeed realized that I misused the function and managed to get sprintf working after disabling the compiler security issue, but the strcat solution seems easier to me.